# Line by line reading, seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

this code gives an instant seg fault,I tried placing printf's all over, I even tried to printf something just after the int=0; line but no matter what I did, it does not print anything but a segmentation fault. The file exists, also its location is the same with where I do the execution.
The file includes city names, one name on each line, nothing else, how do I read them and store them in an array :/
what if there was a number after each city, would the reading still be the same?

```
NewYork 5
LosAngeles 12
California 7
```

and the code;

```
    int i=0;

    char **city_names = malloc(sizeof(char*));

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("abc.txt","r");

    while(!feof(fp)){

        city_names[i] = realloc(city_names[i],sizeof(char)*255);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",city_names[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: You should run your code in a debugger; it will tell you which line caused the segfault.

Comment: That's still wrong.  You only have allocated 1 pointer in the top list.  The realloc doesn't belong on the string size.  Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only allocating a single char * of memory in your malloc then accessing beyond it in the while loop.

If you are going to do a 2D `malloc` array, you need to `malloc` each pointer, then `malloc` assign a `malloc` into each to the max string size (yuck).

```
char **city_names = malloc(sizeof(char *) * kNumCities);

for(int i = 0; i < kNumCities; i++)
  city_names[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * kMaxStringSize);
```

Or do something like `char city_name[3][256]` instead to get it up and running.

I'd also like to add that this sort of reading is very unsafe.  You are reading an unknown amount of bytes into a fixed buffer size.  If the string you read in were more than 255 bytes, you will destroy memory.  You'd be better off using an `fread()` into a fixed size buffer type solution (or `ftell()` then file and read it all in at once for best efficiency) and then do your reading off the buffer.  Not to mention all the overhead of `malloc` and `realloc` (they do add up).

Comment: since I dont know how many city does the file include, I cannot specify a memory like you said. Can I use realloc for the same purpose then?

Comment: If possible, scan the whole file to get a city count, then alloc and read.  x2 file reading, but memory efficient.  Or Alloc a large chunk of cities - you know what is reasonable - and then realloc again if needed.  Beware, realloc is really hard on memory if this is an embedded type solution where memory fragmentation matters.

Comment: I'd also read the whole file into memory and work with it from there if possible - that allows the most flexibility with algorithms and such.

Comment: I am issuing with speed problems also, x2 file reading costs a lot. But if needed, I will go like that, thank you for explanation :)

Comment: Code like this screams for vector<string> if you could do C++.  Takes all the sloppy malloc code and hides it away.

Comment: Actually it is a research for c that I should do,kinda homework though, I will take city names,distances between them and store them in a structure, make those structures in a form of linked lists, then I will try to implement a shortest path algorithm. Efficiency is extremely important, didn't manage to choose a way yet, still struggling..

Comment: Like the traveling salesman problem?  NP Hard and all that?  You know you are asking for it... :)

Comment: yep unfortunately, I have no experience on C but they asked me to do that in a week, this question is just a start, the other parts that I will not be able to do is comin up next :P

Comment: I shoulda add that it is guaranteed that city names will not be longer than 255 bytes, so are you still suggesting your way to solve this, I will have to search for fread and ftell and also their use, which I don't have time to do so.

Answer (score 1):

And the `while(!feof(fp))` logic is wrong too; for an empty file it still tries to scanf something and increments `i`.

**Never test for EOF before you read in C. Test after reading.**

The idiomatic code to iterate over characters on stdin in C is

```
int c; /* NOT char. */

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  /* do something with c */
}
```

To iterate over lines:

```
char line[MAXLINE];
while (fgets (line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
   /* do something with line */
}
```

Comment: that's really useful, but to use the second part of your answer, I will need to count the number of lines, so I think what is the best and easy way for me to write this code is counting the lines first, I will try that then, thanks :)

Comment: No. Just use `int num_lines = 0;` before the loop, and `++num_lines` inside it. That gives you the number of lines when done. If you need to save them, use malloc and memcpy.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i=0;
    char **city_names = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt","r");

    while(!feof(fp)){
        city_names[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
        if(1!=fscanf(fp,"%s %*d",city_names[i]))break;
        ++i;
        city_names = (char**)realloc(city_names, (i+1)*sizeof(char*));
    }

    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: if(1!=fscanf(fp,"%s %*d",city_names[i]))break;
Could you please explain this line further, i.e. why did you use %*d, I mean what is the purpose of the star, I know that compiler complains it for something when I write %d only.

Comment: @user1128905 - your reading data format like `NewYork 5` but your code `fscanf(fp,"%s",city_names[i]);` , this is ignore int data. `%*d` is ignore this position digit data.